# Get real client IP address using websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, ip

I use websocket and nodejs. Is there anyway for the server backend to get the real client's IP address even if it is spoofed?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which depends on express.js;

As I remember, using express with Node.js, you could set app.set('trust proxy', true) so then req.ip will return the real IP address. (even behind proxy).
[For further information](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip)
In WebSocket & Nodejs, you access request's information. maybe express could help.